# ajax.reload() no sirve

Tags: jquery, flask, datatable

Tengo un problema con mi código, necesito la actualización de mi datatable cada que ingreso un nuevo registro, hago update o elimino, sin embargo, esto no funciona, he tenido que usar el `redirect_url` de flask para que se carguen denuevo los datos. Estoy usando conexión pyodbc. Tengo un botón dentro de mi form, pero la actualización del ajax siempre me genera un error de

> DataTables warning: table id=usuarios - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1

Al quitar la linea del ajax, este error desaparece pero no se recarga la datatable

````
@app.route('/eliminar_usuarios', methods=['POST'])
def eliminar_usuarios():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        nueva_sesion = request.form['nombreSesion']
        conn = conexionsql()
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute('DELETE FROM CONSULTORES where sesionConsultor = ?', (nueva_sesion))
        cursor.execute('DELETE FROM USUARIOS where sesionUsuarios= ?', (nueva_sesion))
        conn.commit()
        


        conn.close()
        return jsonify({'success': True, 'message': 'El registro se ha eliminado con éxito'})
    return jsonify({'success': False, 'message': 'Error al eliminar el registro'})
    ```

Este es mi JS

function eliminarRegistro() {

    var nombreSesion = $('#nombreSesion').val();

  
    var formData = {
      nombreSesion: nombreSesion,
   
    };
    // Realizar una solicitud POST AJAX para eliminar el registro
    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/eliminar_usuarios',  // La URL de la ruta en Flask
    data: formData,
    success: function (response) {
            if (response.success) {
                // Muestra un mensaje de éxito
                alert(response.message);

                // Cierra el modal o realiza cualquier otra acción necesaria
                $('#editModal').addClass('hidden');

                $('#usuarios').DataTable().ajax.reload()
            } else {
                // Maneja errores o muestra mensajes de error si es necesario
                alert('Error al guardar los cambios: ' + response.message);
            }
        },
        error: function (error) {
            // Maneja los errores aquí (opcional)
            console.error('Error al guardar los cambios:', error);
        }
    });
  }



<button type="button" class="bg-slate-400 ml-2 text-white px-2 py-2 text-sm mt-5 rounded focus:outline-none hover:bg-slate 500 hover:text-white transition duration-300 ease-in-out transform hover:scale-110" onclick="eliminarRegistro()"><i class="fa-solid fa-trash"></i> Eliminar Registro</button>
````

Comment: el problema es el json segun el mensaje pareciera que esta roto ... en algun lugar  la datatable esta siendo poblada con informacion de un json... trata de imprimir ese json por pantalla o almacenarlo en un archivo en el backend para evaluar si hay algo rompiendo el json ...